# Linking to sms app with url body

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I am having an error when I want to share url using Linking.openURL the sms app is cutting off my url after the & :

This is my url `app://into/app/?bar=true&footer=1234&lorem=51`
and the sms app receives this url `bestest://into/app/?bar=true` does not appears the second parameter.

Comment: Use: `encodeURIComponent("bar=true&footer=1234&lorem=51");` for the querystring parameters

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to open the default's messaging app for your user with a body that includes a URL and some other data, you might want to take a look at [this package](https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications) called [`react-native-communications`](https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications)

> ```
> text(phoneNumber, body)
>
> phoneNumber - String
> body - String
> ```